# Linked List or Splay Tree Data structure

Tags: delphi

I working on a graph problem which could be described with the image below. The Basic Class type (TSubGraph) has number of edges which connect her to the outside world.

Now It comes to the point where I need to investigate the dependencies between the individual sub graphs. They form a hierarchy tree  like below which means I need to create a splay tree class for my data,  or on the other hand I could imagine a linked list to hold the data. (TObjectlist)

I do not need to make exhaustive search over the tree, I'm more concerned on the administration of the edge / connections of two sub graphs.

What is the recommended data structure inspect to the programming languages of Delphi.
I guess e.g. T Interface (like   ) is not a good solution

[image: DATA STRUCTURE IMAGE]

L1, L2 ..... Lx   - number of levels,  variable

e1, e2 .....eN  - number of edge of a Sub graph,  the number is identical for each Sub graph type,  if e_x goes to a higher hierarchically graph I paint e_x on top otherwise I paint it on the buttom side

M1 ....  Mx   - number of Sub graphs, some sub graphs are identical

Comment: I'm not sure why you have multiple parent links in nodes. They all point the the same parent though. Can you explain a bit about the data that you're storing this this tree? If you reduce the tree so each child has only one parent, it's a simple tree.

Comment: Check out: http://www.e-reading.biz/bookreader.php/142043/The_Tomes_Of_Delphi_Algorithms_And_Data_Structures.pdf

Comment: the multible connection information represents the connection information , The algo behind is dealing with that ( but not part of the question)

Comment: also add a few more information in the Q, hope this make it more clear

Comment: The problem is you mention a tree, but the above picture is not a tree, it's a graph. Tree traversal and graph traversal are two very different things with very different answers.

Comment: what I'm asking about is the administration of a graph using the Linked list or any tree data structure. If I do not need to search hundreds of times the tree ... I will change a hundreds of times the edges,  sub graph names and so on ...  does this mean I do not benefit from a tree data structure ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39144/discussion-between-johan-and-franz)

Comment: Thanks for the offer, will have a try the next day